# PHP/MySQL Concat to a single column and Update other columns in table

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to only concat new updates to column `updates` and UPDATE the values in the rest of the columns but I've hit bit of a snag that I can't seem to workout.

My SQL looks like this:

```
$query="Update tickets SET product='$product',
        p='$p',
        i='$i',
        summary='$summary',
        workaround='$workaround',
        concat(updates,'$additional_update'),
        status='$status',
        raised_by='$raised_by',
        updated_by_user='$updated_by' WHERE id='$id'";
```

the `updates` column is like a comments column, where new updates are meant to be appended to the existing text.

The error I'm getting on the web server:

```
Update tickets SET product='T-Box', p='00000817766', i='-', summary='Testing update field
\r\nAdding an update\r\ntesting if null works for update', workaround='n/a', concat(updates,' ','test2@18:53:17:second update/n'), status='Open', raised_by='No', updated_by_user='test2' WHERE id='223'
```

Running the query directly in MySQL:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(updates,'test2@18:53:17:second update/n'), status='Open', raised_by='No', updat' at line 1
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify where the value of this statement `concat(updates,'$additional_update')` to be set.

```
Update tickets 
SET    product = '$product',
       p = '$p',
       i = '$i',
       summary = '$summary',
       workaround = '$workaround',
       updates = CONCAT(updates,'$additional_update'),  // <== see this
       status = '$status',
       raised_by = '$raised_by',
       updated_by_user = '$updated_by' 
WHERE id = '$id'
```

Comment: I just needed the `updates = CONCAT(updates,'$additional_update'),` line to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query="Update tickets SET product='$product',
        p='$p',
        i='$i',
        summary='$summary',
        workaround='$workaround',
        updates=concat(updates,'$additional_update'),
        status='$status',
        raised_by='$raised_by',
        updated_by_user='$updated_by' WHERE id='$id'";
```